# Recycler view + each card is list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Can anyone tell me how can I implement a recycler view with each card as list.I have cursor for each card. I can directly inflate view and add item to card but the problem is rendering time. Am looking for an efficient way to crack this down, any help would be appreciated .

Comment: can you explain what you exactly want by any example or code?

Comment: An example , I didn't use the recycler view before .

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: An example which demonstrate different lists inside recycler view